# Mule Imap: Store Email Attachments to a location and forward the email to other ID

Tags: imap, mule

I am using Mule Imap connector to fetch the mails from server.I can get emails with attachments and without, i have used attachments-list evaluator to return me the attachments in the email and using  splitter to iterate through the list and copy the attachments  to folder.
But problem here is i need to forward the same email to another id without attachments and only body.
Since i have used the attachments-list evaluator i am not able to access the Email body.
Any help on how to forward the same email without attachments would be appreciated.

### Below is the configuraiton xml of the flow

```
<imap:connector name="IMAP1" validateConnections="true" doc:name="IMAP" checkFrequency="15000"/>
<expression-transformer name="returnAttachments" doc:name="Expression">
    <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*"/>
</expression-transformer>
    <file:connector name="fileName" doc:name="File">
    <file:expression-filename-parser/>
</file:connector>
<email:email-to-string-transformer name="Email_to_String" doc:name="Email to String"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the message payload in a flow variable before the `expression-transformer` with:

```
<set-variable variableName="emailBody" value="#[message.payload]" />
```

Then restore it before the `smtp:outbound-endpoint`:

```
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.emailBody]" />
```

And remove `email-to-string-transformer`, it's useless.

Comment: Thanks David for replying , i have set the variable before expression transformer as suggested but NullPayload is set for the variable.    <set-variable variableName="emailBody" value="#[message.payload]" />
     <expression-transformer name="returnAttachments" doc:name="Expression">
        <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*"/>
    </expression-transformer>. plz let me know if i am doing anything wrong here

Comment: Could it be that the email body is actually in one of the attachments?

Comment: thanks david , you are right the emailbody is also added as a attachment when there is actually a attachment in the email (confirmed by checking payload.size which returned 2 when there is a one attachment in the email) , in case there is no attachment in the email payload.size returns me 0.

Comment: hi david any idea on how to filter out the emailbody which is getting added to the attachmenst as {NullPayload} before i upload/store the attachments to external location ?